# How to dynamically launch and kill nodes?

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any best practice and/or guides surrounding how to dynamically launch and kill nodes?

I'm building a small Raspberry Pi based robot, and since it only has 1GB of memory and limited CPU, I don't want every possibly node I use to be loaded, because even a node that's "standing by" consumes about 2-3% of memory.

For example, say I want to start a procedure that looks for QR codes in a video stream. If I don't normally do this, it doesn't make sense to have a QR tracking node running at all times, so I'll want to dynamically launch the node as needed, and then kill it when the procedure is complete. What's the best way to do this using rospy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285269/how-to-dynamically-launch-and-kill-nodes?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For killing a node when you finish processing: [#q250494](https://answers.ros.org/question/250494/how-to-correctly-shutdown-a-rosnode/?answer=250845#post-id-250845)

For starting a node only when it is required, I would suggest using [actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib).

---

Originally posted by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) with karma: 358 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2018-03-13**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/250845/ `Page Not Found`

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-03-13**:
Sorry, edited the link.